# Const correctness with a std::map

Tags: c++, c++11

How much `const` should you apply to a `std::map`?

```
// Given a custom structure, really any type though
struct Foo
{
   int data;
};

// What's the difference between these declarations?
const std::map<int, Foo> constMap;
const std::map<const int, const Foo> moreConstMap;
```

What are the tradeoffs or differences between `constMap` and `moreConstMap`?

The answer may apply to other stl containers too.

**Edit1**.

To provide some more context. One potential use case to consider the difference between the two might be a static lookup table scoped to a .cpp file. Let's say...

```
//Foo.cpp
namespace {
   const std::map<int, Foo> constConfigMap{ {1, Foo{1}}, {2, Foo{2}} };
   // vs
   const std::map<const int, const Foo> moreConstConfigMap{ {1, Foo{1}}, {2, Foo{2}} };
}

void someFunctionDefinition()
{
   Foo blah { constConfigMap.at(2) };

   // do something with blah
}
```

Comment: Keys in `std::map` are `const` anyway, so I think `const int` is redundant. Making the value `const` may be useful in a non-const map. It depends on what you need.

Comment: @drescherjm, how would you modify an instance of Foo once it's part of `constMap`?

Comment: `const std::map<const int, const Foo> moreConstMap;` is moot, this map is fixed to be empty and will never do anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no difference in case of `std::map` aside of them being distinct types.

- As variables are declared `const`, the state of map class itself cannot be changed.
- Only member functions you can call upon it are const-qualified member functions, e.g. `const_iterator find( const Key& key ) const;`

Both const-qualified  `find()` will return a `const_iterator` which would be referring an object of `const std::pair<const int, Foo>` type (just as `operator[]` would) in case of `constConfigMap` and `const std::pair<const int, const Foo>` in case of `moreConstConfigMap`. Those types are nearly synonyms because `second` member of `std::pair` isn't declared as `mutable`. Those are different types though because they are declared by different set of lexemes, which can be illustrated by following code:

```
struct Foo
{
   int data;
   void bar() {}
   // needs to be const-qualified
   bool operator==(const Foo& other) const { return data == other.data; }
};

namespace {
   const std::map<int, Foo> constConfigMap{ {1, Foo{1}}, {2, Foo{2}} };
   // vs
   const std::map<const int, const Foo> moreConstConfigMap{ {1, Foo{1}}, {2, Foo{2}} };
}

int main() {
    auto it1 = constConfigMap.find(1);
    auto it2 = moreConstConfigMap.find(1);
    *it1 == *it2; //  error: no match for ‘operator==’
    it1->second == it2->second;
    it1->second.bar();  // error: passing ‘const Foo’ as ‘this’ argument discards qualifiers

    // neither is ill-formed, what would happen is other question
    const_cast<Foo&>(it1->second).bar(); 
    const_cast<Foo&>(it2->second).bar();
    return 0;
}
```

Compiler would point out that those are different types.

```
      |     *it1 == *it2;
      |     ~~~~ ^~ ~~~~
      |     |       |
      |     |       pair<[...],const Foo>
      |     pair<[...],Foo>
```

You can't change either map or its elements  at all. You can't call non-const-qualified members upon an instance of `Foo` without discarding `const`.

Answer (score 1):

`std::map` contains `pair`'s of `{key, value}`. `key` is always constant and you can not modify it. On the other hand, `value` is modifiable, and if you use `const`, it's not. Because of those `const` at the beginning, anything is modifiable, so the answer to you question is that they are exactly the same. There is no differences.

Comment: both maps have a const in front of them though, so you can't modify anything in both examples.

Comment: Yes, which means that they "behave" exactly the same. Those const inside doesn't aport anything.

Answer (score 1):

As has already been mentioned, keys  in a map are implicitly const.

Making the value a const type will prevent you from using `mymap[k] = v`, because the index operator will return a reference to const. You’ll need to use `insert/emplace` and `erase` to modify the map.

Comment: If the map is declared const though, `insert/emplace` and `erase` wouldn't be allowed either.

Comment: @Panda correct. Declaring the map itself to be const means that you can only set its initial contents.